# How to connect to DB2 using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, db2, activex

I was able to use `Internet Explorer` to connect to `MS Access`, `SQL Server` using `JavaScript` as follows :

```
function connectToDB2() {
        var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
        var ConnString = "Data Source= . . ;    
        connection.open(ConnString); 
}
```

Is it possible to connect to `DB2` ? What is the connection string ?

Comment: It's worth noting that Microsoft has removed ActiveX from their new Edge browser in Windows 10, so this won't work in the future.

Comment: This is in general an extremely bad idea.  For example, anyone can see your DB password.

Comment: That's fine. I am writing an html page for my personal use on my desktop. Nobody will have access to it. I will not update my Internet Explorer. Do I need a special driver for  that ?